# JIRA version and components version history

Tags: jira

Does JIRA keep track of version and components changes (i.e. modification, deletion)? The reason is that if I give user an admin privilage to a Project to update either the version or component, I would like to know what has changed and who made the changes.

If JIRA has this capability, how do I enable and also see the change history? If not, any workaround?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how detailed the logging is, but it doesn't look like there's a full audit trail out of the box. However if you're using 4.x then there's a plugin that allows you to log things a bit better: https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/43203